# How to install Python 2.7 PyQt4 Webkit on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python-2.7, webkit, pyqt4, ubuntu-16.04, qtwebkit

How do you install Webkit for use with PyQt4 (Python 2.7 not Python 3) on Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/840318/importerror-no-module-named-pyqt4-qtwebkit

Comment: link above specifies webkit package installation for python3. python2.7 is very similar -> sudo apt-get install python2.7-pyside.qtwebkit . Note that this version seems to be a bit broken and should probably be avoided. Use something newer

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by

```
sudo apt-get install python-pyside.qtwebkit
```